# Cakephp 3 Html Table Foreach

Tags: php, html, cakephp

i would like to ask about HTML a table which involves different models in a Controller view

inside Users Controller i loaded 3 Models,  Companies, Warehouse, Bank Account

this User can have multiple companies, and each company has warehouse, bank account

when i created 1 company, 1 warehouse 1 bank account,  the table is beautiful. (1 foreach each)

| ID | Name. | Warehouse | Bank Account No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 | Warehouse A | 1234567 |

when i created 2 companies, 1 warehouse, 1 bank account,  the table is messed up, the warehouse and bank account is looping at the 2nd company which has no data yet

| ID | Name. | Warehouse | Bank Account No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 | Warehouse A | 1234567 |
| 2 | Company 2 | Warehouse A | 1234567 |

at ID 2,  this is Warehouse and Bank account is looping from the top

how should i style the HTML for this kind of dynamic table?

| ID | Name. | Warehouse | Bank Account No |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 1 | Warehouse A | 1234567 |
| 2 | Company 2 | -- | -- |

this is the html Code

```
<?php foreach ($companies as $company) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $this->Number->format($company->id) ?></td>
        <td><?= h($company->company_name) ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($warehouses as $warehouse) : ?>
        <td><?= h($warehouse->warehouse_name) ?></td>


            <?php foreach ($bankAccounts as $bankAccount) : ?>
                <td><?= h($bankAccount->account_name) ?></td>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
         
    </tr>
```

Associations of Company Model and Warehouse Model

```
    $this->setTable('companies');
    $this->setDisplayField('company_name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Organizations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Positions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'position_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('BankAccounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
    ]);
  
    $this->hasMany('Warehouses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
    ]);




    $this->setTable('warehouses');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Organizations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'organization_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Companies', [
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Positions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'position_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
```

This is the code from the Controllers

```
    $companies = $this->Companies->find('all')- 
    >where(['Companies.organization_id' => $organizations['id']]);

    $warehouses = $this->Warehouses->find('all')- 
    >where(['Warehouses.company_id' => $organizations['id']]);
```

thank you very much for Anyone's help and guidance.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cakephp 3 Html Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734036/cakephp-3-html-table)

Comment: hi, Andrea, im new to the stack overflow system, i saw that thread mentioning question is closed. so does that mean there will be no new updates?  as i have yet find the solution on how to format the table or make changes in controller.

Comment: Can you show us the [associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/associations.html) of the model?

Comment: hi Shaedrich, please find the associations of Companies and Warehouse as inside the questions, i have updated the codes there.  thank you so much

Comment: And `$warehouses` is something like `$companies->find()->contain(['warehouses'])->extract('warehouses')` or how is that defiened in your html?

Comment: ah, the controllers,  i update the codes of the controllers in the questions on top. please view from the questions